# Amazon Music App

Tags: ios, itunes, windows

I downloaded two albums from Amazon to the Amazon music app on my iphone. I realise now I can only play them back with a network connection.

My iTunes is version 11.2 and I run Windows XP.

Is there any way I can transfer them to my computer/itunes library?

Comment: What OS and version is your computer and iTunes?

Comment: Just upgraded by itunes to the latest version and Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your [Amazon Music Library](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/) and log in, you should be able to select tracks and a download button will appear.

There is an app you will have to download, I'm not sure if it will run on Windows XP though.